# Dynamically allocated memory has to be deleted in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic-allocation

Say I have a `list<TreeNode>` in my program. Every time I use `new` to dynamically allocate a `TreeNode` class and attach it to the list; when the program is over, the list is gone. However, I am not sure if all those elements attached to it will be deleted automatically as the list is gone. Do I still need to go through the list and `delete` all elements myself?

Also, what damage will be caused by a memory leak? When a process is over, its memory space will be released I think, so nothing is actually left behind that harms my computer.

Comment: As you didn't talk about it, I believe that you might want to read about `smart pointers` if you haven't already done so :-) they are related to this kind of problem

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I did not read that before.

Comment: If you have a `list<TreeNode>` you would not use `new` at all. When you insert a `TreeNode` into the list, the value is copied; and the `list` container takes care of the memory management.  Did you actually mean a `list<TreeNode *>`?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I mean list<TreeNode>. Let's say: TreeNode* temp = new TreeNode; list_t.push_back(*temp).

Comment: Then go `delete temp;` immediately after the `push_back`. The `push_back` takes a copy of `*temp`.   In fact you could just go: `Treenode t;  list_t.push_back(t);` and avoid manual memory management entirely.

Comment: Oh, really? I think containers just take some kind of pointers or reference. There is only one copy in memory.

Comment: `list<T>` takes `T` by value. There are two copies in memory after the `push_back`. `list<T*>` would take a pointer. If you don't believe it then either read [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/) for `std::list`, or try modifying `*temp` after you `push_back` and see whether the copy in the list has changed.

Comment: @MattMcNabb You are right! Thank you so much. I am confusing about this for a very long time:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, your `list<TreeNode>` destroys itself because the program has terminated, but now let's say you are in a situation where you are using local `list<TreeNode>` objects that are created and destroyed in a loop or something similar.  That memory leak now turns into something you **do** have to worry about.

Bottom line is your code shouldn't leak, regardless of the situation.  The only exception maybe singleton or similar patterns, where there may be some justification for letting the object "die without cleanup".  But for something like a list class, absolutely no leaks should be present.

In addition, what if the process is not supposed to shut down?  What if it is a mission critical app that must run 24 hours, every day?  That leak now turns into a disaster -- it is you or that (now angry) coworker who will get that phone call in the middle of the night trying to restart the system due to the resources being exhausted.

Comment: Sorry, but what is local list<TreeNode>? Why that should be a problem? All the memory space will be release after the process is over, so I think all those dynamic allocation memory will be available for other processes now.

Comment: @user3352668 - regardless of how you want to do so, there is absolutely no justification for your list class to have memory leaks.  What if the code is this: `int main() { for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i ) { list<TreeNode> myList; //... } }`  Let's say that the `...` contains a lot of nodes added -- what do you think happens?

Comment: @user3352668 - But let's ask you -- if you think memory leaks aren't bad, then why are all of these C++ programmers wasting their time trying to fix them?  Why were smart pointers developed?  Why are there tools to check for memory leaks?  What's all the fuss?  Think about it...

Comment: Oh! Do you mean I should delete all nodes in each for loop otherwise there are lots of memory waste during the process and maybe, at some point of time, the process will crash because running out of memory?

Comment: @user3352668 - Yes.  If you exhaust memory, where does that leave your running program?  What if the program must run 24 hours a day, 7 days a week?  In other words, there is no "process shutdown".

Answer (score 1):

If the *only* thing your `TreeNode` occupies is memory, you don't need to release them when exiting your program. However, if it contains, say, a buffered writing file stream, and you don't release that, there may be data still remaining in the buffer that won't get written to disk. And then you will have data loss. :-)

P.S. I need to add, this strategy of letting the OS free everything for you only applies if your program is short-lived, and you have no "trash" objects (i.e., you need to retain references to all created objects for the program's lifetime). If it's long-lived (but you have no trash objects), just use static memory, and don't do any dynamic allocation. If you have trash objects, you need to free them. No questions asked. :-)

Comment: if the program allocated too much memory, it may significantly decrease the performance of any other running processes.

Comment: @BryanChen I think the OP assumes that _all_ the `TreeNode`s will be needed until the program's exit (think short-lived program that just processes one XML document and quits), and whether there is harm in that case in just exiting the program without releasing the nodes.

Comment: Yes, all the TreeNodes will be needed until the program's exit. In this case, if TreeNode only occupies memories, is it the same whether I delete those objects?

Comment: @user3352668 In that case, deleting those objects is optional.

Comment: still, it is bad style to let program leak and assume OS will do cleanup after program exit, which can be too late.

Comment: @BryanChen I agree it's "bad style", but sometimes, it is actually faster to let your OS deallocate everything en masse than to deallocate them one by one. Just try exiting Firefox after opening 350 tabs, vs simply killing the process. (Hint: one approach may cause lots of swapped-out pages to be paged back in, not very usefully.) :-)

Comment: How about try to shutdown your computer by unplug the power cable vs use the shutdown command from OS?

Comment: @user3352668 Obviously, my answer assumes we're running something very short-lived, and you don't have any "trash" objects during your run. If you do have trash objects, or if it's long-lived, then Paul McKenzie's answer applies. So in general, do free everything, but there are limited circumstances where freeing stuff is optional.

Comment: @BryanChen Actually, I do have virtual appliances that I do "shut down" that way. Especially if the next thing I do is restore from snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you've used `new` to allocate a `TreeNode` object everytime you add it to the list, you're going to have to `delete` that object as well before your `list` is cleared.

**One new = one delete**

Comment: unless you are using smart pointers, which you should be using

Comment: Well the OP said they're using `new`, so I'm just answering the question, not rallying behind the smart pointer bandwagon.